# Array com inputs e um dado específico!

Tags: php, array, loop

só aqui mesmo pra resolver certas coisas.

Estou quebrando a cabeça para fazer esse loop mas não consegui ainda.

Como eu faço para colocar o destaque nessa array() sendo que somente 1 dessas fotos será marcada com o valor 1.

```
$fotos = $this->input->post('fotos[]');
$destaque = $this->input->post('destaque[]');

$foto = array();

foreach ( $fotos as $item => $value){
    array_push($foto, array(
        'idFoto' => $id,
        'img' => $value
        'destaque' => $
    ));
}
```

O resultado que espero é algo assim:

```
array(
array(idFoto => 1,
img => 1.jpg,
destaque => Null),

array(idFoto => 2,
img = 2.jpg,
destaque => 1), //Nesse caso o radio foi checado

array(idFoto => 3,
img => 3.jpg,
destaque => Null)
);
```

No caso do html eu faço o input de várias fotos e uma delas eu seleciono como destaque.

Comment: O destaque é um _array_ também? O que tem na variável `$destaque`? é o índice de algum elemento do _array_ `$fotos`?

Comment: $destaque vem de um radio e se checado grava um valor 1 mas é somente um das fotos vai conter o valor 1. no caso eu me esqueci de colocar o colchete ai...mas o colchete não é a questão...

Comment: No caso *destaque* é o ID da foto ou o índice do array? Pode dar um exemplo do resultado final que você espera?

Comment: @JacielPlacidino cada foto tem um _radio button_?

Comment: Pra ficar mais fácil, você pode fazer um `var_dump` das variáveis `$fotos` e `$destaque` e/ou também postar o HTML referente ao formulário, colocando essas informações no corpo da pergunta clicando em [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/82275/edit) logo abaixo da sua pergunta.

Comment: @KaduAmaral sim pra cada foto tem um radio destaque[].

Comment: @JacielPlacidino, tente assim em cada rádio coloque o `value` com um número de `0` incrementando um a cada foto, `0,1,2,3,...` e ali no loop coloque assim `'destaque' => ($destaque == $item ? 1 : 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use o `foreach` para alterar o 'status' do destaque quando o *idFoto* combinar com o valor do `$destaque`. Fiz um exemplo com array no [*Ideone*](http://ideone.com/ZUiMZG), mas deixei aqui apenas o loop.

O resultado é o `destaque = 1`, apenas no *array de índice 1*( correspondente a *foto idFoto 2*)

```
foreach( $fotos as $n => $foto )
{
    if( $foto['idFoto'] === $destaque /* 2 */ )
    $fotos[$n]['destaque'] = 1;
}
```

### <sub>**Output**</sub>

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [idFoto] => 1
            [img] => 1.jpg
            [destaque] => 
        )

    [1] => Array(
            [idFoto] => 2
            [img] => 2.jpg
            [destaque] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array(
            [idFoto] => 3
            [img] => 3.jpg
            [destaque] => 
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo de como fazer tipo de implementação é da seguinte forma:

#### Formulário

```
<form>
   <?php
      for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
   ?>
   <input type="text" name="foto[<?=$i?>]"><input type="radio" name="destaque" value="<?=$i?>"><br>
   <?php
      }
   ?>
</form>
```

#### PHP

```
<?php
   // Fotos é um array
   $fotos = $this->input->post('fotos');
   // Destaque é o número do índice da foto que será o destaque
   $destaque = $this->input->post('destaque');

   $foto = array();

   foreach ( $fotos as $item => $value){
       array_push($foto, array(
           'idFoto' => $id,
           'img' => $value
           'destaque' => intval($item == $destaque)
       ));
   }

?>
```

A expressão `$item == $destaque` verifica se o índice do elemento atual no *loop* é igual ao número do destaque que retornará `true` ou `false`
a função `intval` transformará o resultado *boolean* em numérico `1` ou `0`.